# Tableau: Database error 0x80040E14: JOIN expression not supported

Tags: database, join, tableau-api

Does anyone understand what this error means?

All I did was set a filter as a range for the number of records when this error popped up.

I am using Tableau verion 9.3

Comment: What is your data source? Can you post a sample workbook?

Comment: What are data source you are using most probably this issue could be  datatype miss match in join..